# Ambigous column in POJO result query room android

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, android-room, pojo

I have two tables `sites` and `groups` with the data classes like that

```
@Entity(tableName = "sites")
data class Site(

    @PrimaryKey
    @ColumnInfo(name = "site_id")
    val siteId: Int,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "description", defaultValue = "")
    val description: String

)

@Entity(tableName = "groups")
data class Group(

    @PrimaryKey
    @ColumnInfo(name = "group_id")
    var groupId: Int,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "site_id")
    val siteId: Int,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "description", defaultValue = "")
    val description: String
)
```

so as we can see each Site has a list of Groups.

What i want is, given a `site_id` and `group_id` how can i get a result pojo like that

```
class SiteGroup {
    
    @Embedded
    var site: Site? = null
    
    @Relation(parentColumn = "site_id", entityColumn = "site_id", entity = Group::class)
    var groups: Group? = null
    
}
```

I have tried the below

```
@Query("""Select * from sites
        inner join groups on groups.site_id = :siteId
        where site_id = :siteId and groups.group_id = :groupId
    """)
    fun getByIdWithGroup(siteId: Int, groupId: Int): LiveData<SiteGroup>
```

but i get the following exception on build time

```
error: There is a problem with the query: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (ambiguous column name: site_id)
    public abstract androidx.lifecycle.LiveData<com.example.model.entities.pojos.SiteGroup> getByIdWithGroups(int siteId, int groupId) 
Incremental annotation processing requested, but support is disabled because the following processors are not incremental: androidx.room.RoomProcessor (DYNAMIC).
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. The problem was the `where site_id`.
The correct way is

```
@Query("""Select * from sites
        inner join groups on groups.site_id = :siteId
        where sites.site_id = :siteId and groups.group_id = :groupId
    """)
    fun getByIdWithGroup(siteId: Int, groupId: Int): LiveData<SiteGroup>
```